# Hide header and footer while some specific pages are being loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular 1.x application : How can I hide the header and footer on some specific pages in my app?
I set a 'navigateOut' data property on my state and I use ng-if to show\hide elements (like header and footer) based on this property value. The problem is that when the page is being loaded the state is yet to be set so I can see the elements for a few seconds.

```
  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    template: require('partials/sso.html'),
    controller: 'SignupController as signup',
    data: {
      navigateOut: false
    }
  })


   <app-footer ng-if="$state.current.data.navigateOut !== false"></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the ng-if condition in a div tag surrounded by it instead of app-footer tag like

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.data.navigateOut !== false">    
<app-footer ></app-footer>
</div>
```

or by using ng-class with the 'hidden' class name to hide the element instead of using ng-if or ng-show/ng-hide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I can still see the elements while the page is being loaded and they still disappear only when loading is finished

Comment: Did you try using the ng-class also?

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of is creating a separate template and controller for the headers and footers. Have multiple ui-views named under the header, footer, and content.
For each state you have load only the required components.

If the issue still persists it could be due to the ng-animate library which is enabled by default. Try disabling it

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"><!-- Content --></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>


$stateProvider
    .state('myapp', {
        views: {
          'header': {
            template:'header.html',
            controller:'HeaderController'
          },
          'content': {
            template:'content.html'
          },
          'footer': {
            template:'footer.html',
            controller:'FooterController'
          }
       }    
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have many states in my app and only few of them should hide the header and the footer. How can I config my states in a way that by default they will load all the components and only when required, the header and footer won't be loaded?